# Laravel 7.x Only the profile's Owner and some roles may enter or do action

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at Laravel and I don't quite sure how to get User's session so he can see his own profile but can't be seen by other users except for the Admin role.

this is what I thought

**profile/ProfileControllers.php**

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    if(Gate::allows('manageUsers')){
        return view('Profile.Users.profile')->with([
            'user'  =>$user,
        ]);
    }
    if ($user->id === $user->id) {
        return view('Profile.Users.profile')->with([
            'user'  =>$user,
        ]);
    }
    return redirect(route('home'));

}
```

I thought using `$user->id == $user->id` means the `session user id = this id http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/users/{id}` but it is not and i can see the other user's profiles using a single user.

*manageUsers* inside the gate is the user admins like (cashier, sales, etc)

I reckon some other methods are using middleware in the web route. But I failed to understand what's to put on my middleware

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::namespace('Profile')->prefix('profile')->name('profile.')->middleware('?')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/users', 'ProfilesController', ['except' =>['store', 'create']]);
});
```

what I'm trying to approach is,
Only the owner of the profile and some roles can see the profile. and the guest will be redirected to home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you want something like this?

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    if(Gate::allows('manageUsers')){
        return view('Profile.Users.profile')->with([
            'user'  =>$user,
        ]);
    }
    if (auth()->user()->id === $user->id) {
        return view('Profile.Users.profile')->with([
            'user'  =>$user,
        ]);
    }
    return redirect(route('home'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$user->id == auth()->id()`

Comment: Please, do not post suggestions as answers. If you are not sure it will work better write it as a comment under the question.

Comment: You answer looks like a suggestion. Update it and explain how exactly it works and why it fixes the issue. It will be received a lot better and attract more attention. People more likely will try solutions that have explanations. It is the lack of understanding that leads them here in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own middleware and put your login theri.

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

Then register this to Kernel.php file

Inside middleware

```
 If(auth()->user()->type == 'Admin'){
      //Ruj your script inside if block , and instead of attribute TYPE 
      //you must put what you have used in databse to check if user 
      //is admin or not.
  }
```